# How to use MinGW-w64 with Cygwin?

Tags: gcc, cygwin, mingw, mingw-w64

MinGW-w64 has been available with Cygwin at least since [**December 2010**](ftp://www.fruitbat.org/pub/cygwin/circa/2010/12/30/094549/index.html).
However I am having hard time using this to compile almost anything. I have set symbolic links with [**alternatives**](http://linux.die.net/man/8/alternatives)

```
p=x86_64-w64-mingw32
alternatives \
    --install /usr/bin/gcc.exe gcc /usr/bin/$p-gcc.exe 0 \
    --slave /usr/bin/ar.exe ar /usr/bin/$p-ar.exe
```

For example if I try to compile `wget`

```
./configure --without-ssl
make
```

Errors (edited for brevity)

```
connect.o:connect.c:(.text+0x3f): undefined reference to `__imp_htons'
connect.o:connect.c:(.text+0xbe7): undefined reference to `__imp_ntohs'
connect.o:connect.c:(.text+0xd96): undefined reference to `run_with_timeout'
```

If I use

- MinGW shell with MinGW gcc
- Cygwin shell with Cygwin gcc (`gcc4-core`)

Then Wget will compile.

Based off ak2 answer, this seems to work

```
./configure --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --disable-ipv6 --without-ssl
make
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

ak2 is partially incorrect as stated [here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/explaining-build-host-target-509739/).

The correct option is `--host=x86_64-w64-mingw32`, as you found out. `--target` is used for building a cross-compiler itself.  The options are:

- `--build`: What you are building on
- `--host`: What you are building for
- `--target`: If what you are building is a cross-compiler, what that cross-compiler will build for.

Answer (score 7):

Cygwin's MinGW-w64 compiler is a cross-compiler, because it's hosted on Cygwin but targeting MinGW-w64. You just need to tell `configure` about it using the `--target` option, like so:

```
--target=x86_64-w64-mingw32
```

That way, `make` will be invoking the appropriate tools. You'll also need to install or build MinGW-w64 versions of any libraries that the package you're trying to build depends on.

Bending the alternatives system to have the tools in `/usr/bin` point at the MinGW-w64 ones is not a good idea, because that way you'll be using MinGW tools with Cygwin headers and libraries, which leads to errors like the ones you quoted above.

Comment: I have installed the package `mingw64-x86_64-gcc-g++` in Cygwin. However, `which g++` does not show any `g++`. Where is the installed `mingw64` compiler? For this `mingw64-x86_64-gcc-g++` what should I set in `./configure --target=???`